# How to save live the data from Fiddler to use it for other program?

Tags: save, package, live, fiddler, autosave

I use Fiddler2 and I capture packages.
I want this packages to save live or autosave to a directory.
So I want to found it there and proccesing it.
Any suggest?

Comment: I have this :HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 11:27:29 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Content-Length: 53656
it`s a script : http://improve.dk/using-fiddler-to-automatically-download-streamed-mp3s/  but I want for this kind what I have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write a script (Rules > Customize Rules > OnBeforeResponse) to do this; see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/httpfiddler/fiddler$20automatically$20save/httpfiddler/s7GHCLcJJF8/GoAGLHbw-KAJ for example.